# How to access non-static data members in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to access my systems temperature using this: http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/developers.html

as you can see, the data structure is this:

```
typedef struct core_temp_shared_data
{
    unsigned int    uiLoad[256];
    unsigned int    uiTjMax[128];
    unsigned int    uiCoreCnt;
    unsigned int    uiCPUCnt;
    float       fTemp[256];
    float       fVID;
    float       fCPUSpeed;
    float       fFSBSpeed;
    float       fMultiplier;    
    char        sCPUName[100];
    unsigned char   ucFahrenheit;
    unsigned char   ucDeltaToTjMax;
}CORE_TEMP_SHARED_DATA,*PCORE_TEMP_SHARED_DATA,**PPCORE_TEMP_SHARED_DATA;
```

however, i am new to c++ programming and do not understand how to access the data of one of those things. i have tried this:

```
cout << core_temp_shared_data::fTemp;
```

but it just spits out this error code:

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member 'core_temp_shared_data::fTemp'|
```

what is a valid use?

Comment: Declaring the pointer `PCORE_TEMP_SHARED_DATA` and pointer-to-pointer `PPCORE_TEMP_SHARED_DATA` *typedef*-s don't bring you much and actually can make your code less readable and less understandable. It is important, when reading your code, to understand quickly what is a pointer...

Comment: I didnt put that there. the developers of the library did.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new object of that type, set the members to a meaningful value, and access it through the object.

```
core_temp_shared_data obj;
obj.fMultiplier = 0;
std::cout << obj.fMultiplier;
```

Comment: i have adapted that code to:
    core_temp_shared_data obj;
    obj.fTemp = 0;
    cout << obj.fTemp;
but it just spits out this error: 

   C:\Users\Ryan\Dropbox\C++\Serial_System_Monitor\main.cpp|7|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'float [256]'|

Comment: this is not working. every single time i run this it just prints 0. i need to be able to retrieve information from it and this just gives me the same thing every time.

Comment: @user1803425 and you're surprised it prints out `0`?

Comment: like i said... i am a noob.

Comment: @user1803425 then you should probably learn C++ from a book, not just by dumping snippets of code in your IDE hoping it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the struct/class like in C.

```
CORE_TEMP_SHARED_DATA shared_data;
shared_data.fVID = 0.5f;
```

Or via dynamic allocation:

```
PCORE_TEMP_SHARED_DATA shared_data = new CORE_TEMP_SHARED_DATA;
shared_data->fVID = 0.5f;
```